# Displaying point cloud footprint from PostGIS using GeoServer and OpenLayers?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, lidar, pdal

I'm using PDAL to import LAS files into PostGIS.

The tutorial provided by boundless is great, and shows how to display the data in patches, but it doesn't cover displaying the table 'footprint'.

I need to display the coverage area as a footprint/wireframe using Geoserver and OpenLayers.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To my amateur eye, you need to cast the PDAL patches as geometries and union the result. `ST_Union()` or `ST_MemUnion()` for memory efficiency.

```
SELECT st_union(pa::geometry) FROM medford;
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I'm on the wrong computer this morning too!  :)